# Regular expression to allow multiple and single chars

Tags: regex

```
@**** temp between 100.75 - 115.00 ---Important notice. Good bye..,,... --- **** //\\
```

I need a regular expression to return

```
temp between 100.75 - 115.00 Important notice. Good bye.
```

allowed characters: alphabets (upper and lower), single -, single ., single ,
numbers, single space, single ?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=@\*{4}\s).*?(?=\.{2},{2})
```

If `lookaheads` are supported then you can try this way.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/21

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=@\*{4}\s).*?(?=[.,]{2,})";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"@**** temp between 100.75 - 115.00 ---Important notice. Good bye..,,... --- **** //\\";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to resolve it in C#. The expression truncated all alphabets and numbers!

Comment: I got: @**** ..,,... --- **** //\\

Comment: I appreciate your response. 

This is my input string:
@**** temp between 100..75 - 115.00 ---Important notice. Good bye..,,... --- **** //\\"

Expected output: 
temp between 100.75 - 115.00 Important notice. Good bye.

But I get 
"temp between 100" 
and rest of the string is completely truncated due to Match and not Replace

Comment: it seems yours will catch the three `-` in the middle and miss the `.` at the end.